# Can I retrieve Youtube playlist views through the Youtube API?

Tags: api, youtube, playlist

I asked in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21833/how-do-i-see-how-many-views-a-youtube-playlist-has) how to see how many views a Youtube playlist has. Unfortunately, it has been removed from the UI. Can I retrieve Youtube playlist views through the Youtube API?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I think, there is no way to get round it in API requests. According to [YouTube's Playlist Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list), it does not provide a `statistics` parameter which is responsible for providing various stats about videos. I was also looking for a similar use case and I came across this question. Maybe someone else can find a (hackable-)way along the way.